# Using findstr to match a variable from a for statement in Batch against a user define variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to get a match from user input i.e. 201 to one of the server names I am using in a variable in POP1.txt

POP1 contains a list with newlines, such as

```
gui-server201-pop1
gui-server101-pop1
gui-server301-pop1
```

In CASE_DC1 I am using the for statement, which worked for a slightly different use case, but now I am trying to filter the server names to user input.

For example, if the user enters 101, I would like the for statement to only open a putty connection to gui-server101-pop1, without having to make individual case statements for each.

I believe the issue is with how I'm calling %%a in

```
echo.%%a | findstr C:\"%portal%">nul && (
```

As cmd prompt testing returns a value for %portal% but not %%a

```
    set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;%PATH%

    @echo off & setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    Title %~n0
    Mode 60,5 & Color 17
    set /p usr="Enter Username : "
    Call:InputPassword "Enter Password " pwd
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    set /p portal="Select the portal (101, 201, 301): "

    set /p DC="Move to a Data Centre (Type DC1 / DC2): "
    2>NUL Call:CASE_%DC%
    If ERRORLEVEL 1 Call :DEFAULT_CASE

    EXIT /B

    ::***********************************
    :InputPassword
    Cls
    echo Username: %usr%
    echo.
    set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host '%1' -AsSecureString ; ^
        $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
          [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
            for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set %2=%%p
    )
    goto :eof     
    ::***********************************

    ::***********************************
    :CASE_dc1 or CASE_Dc1 or CASE_DC1
        for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (POP1.txt) do (
            echo.%%a | findstr /c:"%portal%">nul && (
                start putty -ssh %%a -l %usr% -pw %pwd% -m ENABLE.txt -t
                )
                || (
                echo.Not Found "%portal%"
                )
        )
        for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (POP2.txt) do (
            echo.%%a | findstr /c:"%portal%">nul && (
                start putty -ssh %%a -l %usr% -pw %pwd% -m DISABLE.txt -t
                )
                || (
                echo.Not Found "%portal%"
                )
        )
        goto END_CASE
    :CASE_dc2 or CASE_Dc2 or CASE_DC2
        for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (POP1.txt) do (
            echo.%%a | findstr /c:"%portal%">nul && (
                start putty -ssh %%a -l %usr% -pw %pwd% -m DISABLE.txt -t
                )
                || (
                echo.Not Found "%portal%"
                )
        )
        for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (POP2.txt) do (
            echo.%%a | findstr /c:"%portal%">nul && (
                start putty -ssh %%a -l %usr% -pw %pwd% -m ENABLE.txt -t
                )
                || (
                echo.Not Found "%portal%"
                )
        )
        goto END_CASE
    :DEFAULT_CASE
        echo Not a valid option "%DC%" (DC1 / DC2)
        VER > NUL
        set /p DC="Choose a Data Centre (Type DC1 / DC2): "
        2>NUL Call:CASE_%DC%
        If ERRORLEVEL 1 Call :DEFAULT_CASE
    :END_CASE
        VER > NUL
        goto :eof
    ::***********************************
```

Thanks

Comment: I would change `findstr C:\"%portal%"` to `FindStr/C:"%portal%"` although based on your file content just `Find "%portal%-"` would do.

Comment: Thanks' I did realise this a few minutes ago, however forgot to update till just now. Altough I have updated to this code, I still don't get a putty session opening. Just to say, removing the pipe to findstr opens all the servers in the text file in one whack, but still nogo to isolate it by the search term.

Comment: Is the first line of your script, `set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;%PATH%`, really there?

Comment: Yeah. Is that bad? The work server always resets local path on logout.

Comment: I see no point in it whatsoever! I would simply `Set "TTY=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PuTTY\putty"` then use `Start "" "%TTY%"` instead of using `start putty`. _There's no need to make temporary changes to an important system variable_. If you decide not to change that the move the statement beneath the opening `@echo off` line.

Comment: Thank you Compo, I will make sure to set that to a variable, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have modified the file as described, but as yet, I am still not getting a "True result" from the findstr or find. When leaving @echo on, my output is  || (, suggesting that the statement still returns false. I can see my Variables correctly with REM, and the for statement looping through the search.

Comment: That's probably because your conditional test is against the `start` command, not the `putty` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution turned out to be a single line statement, as putting it across several lines didnt work. i.e.

```
echo.%%a | findstr /c:"%portal%">nul && ( start putty -ssh %%a -l %usr -pw %pwd%) || ( echo.NotFound)
```